# How to ignore global css?

Tags: html, css

I have a html page with div like below.

```
<div id="container">/* lots of nested html with elements like div, ul, li etc */</div>
```

Above html page also has lots of other html elements outside of the above div.
Now, we have a global css file like style.css which is included in each html file. It has a css rule like following.

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Now, i do not want these rules to be applied to any of the elements in the following div.

```
<div id="container">/* lots of nested html with elements like div, ul, li etc */</div>
```

Css rules should be applied to rest of the stuff in the html.

How should I do this?

Comment: Have you seen this [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)?  maybe can help

Comment: I can not change the global styles.css or any css rule in it. Anything that I can do in the html only? I just want padding :0 not to apply to any of the elements inside my div.

Comment: You can try padding:initial [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial), but i think this set the padding to the default value

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy, you can combine the effects of [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [:is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) CSS selectors. Here is a working example.

```css
:is(body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td):not(#container *) {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Inside</li>
    <li>The</li>
    <li>Container</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul>
  <li>Outside</li>
  <li>The</li>
  <li>Container</li>
</ul>
```

Run the snippet and you can see that the styles aren't applied to the list inside the container. What's happening here is that we're selecting all those elements with the `:is` selector and then deselecting all the children of the `#container`using the `:not` selector.

Comment: Thanks but I can not change the existing css. Is there any other way?

Comment: Add in every html file on bottom of body <style> </style> with this exeptions ? But it must be loaded after style.css file.

Comment: @ashishjmeshram you can use the rule is another CSS file and include it in every page if that's the case.